SpringBoot3 does not log stacktrace
I'm migrating vom Spring5 to SpringBoot3.
Unfortunately (beside tons of other problems with e.g. spring security 6), spring boot does not log the problems and stacktraces, but keeps quiet.
e.g.:
To research a little bit, why only empty results are delivered by the embedded tomcat without any information in log (this is not a joke) i tried to find out whether the controller is instantiated or not - and threw a runtimeEx in the constructor, so spring would log an error if it tries to do so:
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

public RegisterController() {
    throw new RuntimeException("wtf");
}


I expected to find a stracktrace, but all spring says is
2024-07-07 14:04:34,475 WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registerController' defined in file [/.../login/controller/RegisterController.class]: Failed to instantiate [....login.controller.RegisterController]: Constructor threw exception
application.properties:
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE

Whatever the intention to hide most important information in a (maybe) critical situation on a production system is (imho absolutely questionable): how can we log the stackstrace?

do you have some logback-spring.xml configuration? or some other logging config?

I did have them before, and deleted it for researching the causes.

well default logging configuration (meaning absense of any config files) definitely prints stack trace, so the only possible explanation would be some misconfiguration. As long as logging deviates from the default (expected) behavior you have some config file somewhere.

found it: there was a logback-test.xml left .... unsure why that is used with not running in test-mode, but it seems to be used nevertheless.
THANKS, Javid!!

See comment of Javid Asgarov (thx!!):
be sure, that there is NO logging config file of any kind in any subdirectories or anywhere else in the classpath, even if they are named for special logback modes like lockback-test.xml - despite of they should not be used: they WILL.
